# Trying to create a query using ArcGIS android API

Tags: java, android, arcgis-android-api

I am trying to create a query to take the selected item from a spinner and query it with information from a URL. But anytime I run it, it throws an exception saying my parameters are invalid.

Code:

```
QueryParameters qryLotNums = new QueryParameters ();
qryLotNums.setReturnGeometry(true);
qryLotNums.setOutFields(new String[] {mLotNumColName});
qryLotNums.setWhere(String.valueOf(mSpnParcels.getSelectedItem()));

//Create a query task:
mLotLayerURL = getString(R.string.basemap_url_query) + "/" + mLotLayerID;
QueryTask qtask = new QueryTask(mLotLayerURL);

// To run query
try {
    /** ================================
     * add your code here
     * ==================================
     */
    //Get the graphics from the Query Task:
    FeatureResult fSet= qtask.execute(qryLotNums);
} ...
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the full error message include the classname of the exception.